# Aligning elements in row to top?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align the contents of a row, which is inside of a container, to the top of said row.

This is my current html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="ticket">
           <!-- content -->
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS for ticket:

```
<style>
    .ticket{
        border:5px solid black;
        border-radius: 15px 50px 30px 5px;
        width:20%;
        height: fit-content;
        display:inline-block;
        clear: left;
        margin-left:30px;
        background-color:#eee;
    }
</style>
```

"row" and "container" are both bootstrap.

[Trying to align the 'tickets' with the top (red line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxEH1.png)

I've tried using *align-content* and *align-items* but neither seem to be doing anything. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Please make this question bit more clear.

Comment: I'm trying to align the tickets, inside a row, to the top. The image in the description should help explain - tickets should be pinned to the red line.

Comment: you should provide more code and also your css. Also instead of commenting, you should edit and update your question with more information. Also think about to create a fiddle, pen or make use of the SO code section please. Then I am pretty sure we can find a solution for you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `align-items: flex-start;` in container of tickets.

```css
.ticket {
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
}
.tick {
  padding:20px;
  border:4px solid #000;
  margin:50px;
  border-radius:0 30px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="ticket">
           <div class="tick">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quisquam adipisci suscipit, labore accusamus, libero ad dolorum officia error quo, et molestiae fugit placeat maxime ratione vel minus delectus magni. Consequatur! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quisquam adipisci suscipit, labore accusamus, libero ad dolorum officia error quo, et molestiae fugit placeat maxime ratione vel minus delectus magni. Consequatur!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quisquam adipisci suscipit, labore accusamus, libero ad dolorum officia error quo, et molestiae fugit placeat maxime ratione vel minus delectus magni. Consequatur!</div>
          <div class="tick">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quisquam adipisci suscipit, labore accusamus</div>
          <div class="tick">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use next css code:

```
.ticket { 
   display: flex;
}

.item-in-container { 
  #flex: 1;
}
```

Uncomment `flex: 1;` if you want them to have the same width

Answer (score 1):

If you used the default behaviour of `bootstrap` it's aligned to the top:

```css
.ticket  {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.ticket:nth-child(2)  {
  height: 70px;
}

.ticket:nth-child(3)  {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="ticket col-3 m-3"></div>
    <div class="ticket col-3 m-3"></div>
    <div class="ticket col-3 m-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```